# dc.js redraw has memory leaks with updated data?

Tags: dc.js

I use dc.js to draw a dataset which is consistently updated every second.

I find browser memory usage keeps rising. So if I open my browser for about 10 mins, the page will crash.

I create a test for this problem and it seems to come from `chart.redraw()`. If I comment out this method, even though the crossfilter is still updating, memory usage is stable.

I put my test code on jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/pbs06zp6/

Comment: This is very interesting - thanks for starting this investigation. I think I'm able to repro using your example and Chrome developer tools (Timeline). It seems like the leak may have to do with transitions - if I [turn them off using chart.transitionDuration(0)](https://jsfiddle.net/exbdhnn8/1/) then memory usage seems to be more stable (and quite a bit lower). Not a great workaround but considering that the [line/area transitions are wrong](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/507) this is maybe not horrible. I've [filed an issue to track this](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1289).